# Помогите разобраться с php-скриптом для VK API

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Написан скрипт для постинга записей в открытые сообщества ВК методом wall.post. Скрипт успешно выполняется и никаких ошибок не выдает, однако новые записи в указанной в скрипте группе не появляются. В чем может быть проблема?

PS. Токен без ограничений по времени получен и вписан в скрипт. Токен для stand-alone приложения.

Скрипт:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8">
<?php
/*
VK-API WALL.POST Отправляем запись в группу методом post, через CURL
*/
$group_id ="-123108209";
$token = "тут мой токен";
$api_ver = "5.74";
$text = file_get_contents('post_data.txt');
$url = sprintf('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $ch, array (
    CURLOPT_POST           => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
        "owner_id"     => $group_id,
        "from_group"   => 1,
        "Message"      => $text,
        "access_token" => $token,
        "v"            => $api_ver,

),
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
));
$query = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if(!$query){
    printf('Error');
    exit;
}
else{
    printf('Success');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: из-за ниского рейтинга комент писать не могу,если капча то с какого хостера запускаешь сервер должен в рф находиться, чтоб капчи не было

Answer (score 0):

Если группа по типу "Добавь в друзья" то там может быть captha. Посмотри какую ошибку выкидывает VK и интерпретатор (если выкидывает).